# Converting .txt file into a table of characters in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, encryption, converters

Have a little problem here:

Trying to create my own "Aplhabet", which I want to apply on my .txt,.doc,.odt documents to encrypt them.

I wanted to ask, how could I convert the .txt,.doc,.odt file into a list of character, so I can then change them one by one for my own "Alphabets" characters. 
And then convert them back again and save them.

I was trying to use:

```
c = ('test.txt')

with open(c, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as a_file:
   #Here I was trying writing the entry right into the code to be written into the file
   a_file.write('Neco jineho napsaneho')
   for i, v in enumerate(c):
      c[i] = v.replace("N", "3")

with open(c, encoding='utf-8') as a_file:
   print(a_file.read())
```

But since the "c" is a .txt file and not a list, it wount work and just gives me this error:

```
c[i] = v.replace("N", "5")
TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Cheers,

J

Comment: "c" is a string in the context of your file, and strings are immutable objects, meaning you can't assign them values that way.

Comment: "c" is the .txt file I want to convert into a table, so that I can mutate it.
Thats why I am asking, if there is a way to do that

Comment: The line `c = ('test.txt')` makes "c" a string that has the characters `test.txt`. If you want it to have the contents of the actual file, you'll need change it to `c = open('test.txt', 'r').read()`. Then you will have the contents of the file. Even still, you can never assign characters in a string via indexes. So the line `c[i] = v.replace("N", "3")` isn't going to be allowed. If you want c to be a list of lines, you can do `c = open('test.txt','r').readlines()` then that would work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, doing this

```
with open(c, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as a_file:
```

destroys your file contents right away. You have to read it fully before writing it back

Second, `for i, v in enumerate(c):` is iterating on the *filename*. Cannot work! (which explains the error you're getting: you're trying to encrypt the filename *in place*: strings are *immutable*). Anyway, not what you want to do...

And you don't need `enumerate`. Just create a list using listcomp while iterating on the file (file lines)

```
with open(c, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as a_file:
   lines = [v.replace("N", "3") for v in a_file]

# now write the "encrypted" file back using the same name
with open(c, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as a_file:
   a_file.write('Neco jineho napsaneho')
   a_file.writelines(lines)
```

Note: replace `v.replace("N", "3")` by a custom `encrypt(v)` if you want a more complex encryption.

```
lines = [encrypt(v) for v in a_file]
```

with `encrypt` defined as:

```
def encrypt(v):
     return v.replace("N","3").replace("Z","5")
```

(not very efficient, but it's just an example. With a dictionary it would be better)

Comment: Hey Jean, I tried it out, but when I run it, it takes the existing text in the file and adds to it what ever is in a_file.write('') and adds it to the text in the file.

Comment: Is there a way to just read whats in the txt file, convert it and rewrite  the file ?

Comment: can you test again? I just tested and it did exactly that: convert & rewrite. Note that the write mode cannot keep old data.

Comment: When I run it, it just adds whats in a_file.write('') to what ever is in the .txt file already. It changes the N to 3, but looks like this:

Comment: Contents of the txt file: Neco jineho napsaneho3eco jineho napsaneho3eco jineho napsaneho

Comment: please start with a fresh file. The problem of this code is that it overwrites the source. Maybe change the name of the file that you write so you can compare before/after. My code works.

Comment: Alright, I deleted the stuff that was in a_file.write('') and just left the quotation marks and it does convert it ! Thanks mate, really appreciate your help. Have a nice evening!

Comment: One more question, how can I make this  `lines = [v.replace("N", "3") for v in a_file] `  for multiples letters like `lines = [v.replace("M", "6") for v in a_file]` etc... ? I Tried copiing this command and  using it multiple times after each other, but that didnt work. It just deleted the file. Thanks in advance!

Comment: see my note: listcomps are ok when it's simple but of course you need more: Note: replace v.replace("N", "3") by a custom encrypt(v) if you want a more complex encryption.

Comment: I am just begining with Python, so dunno how I would go about it. Anyhow, I figured that If I just create the: `with open(c, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as a_file:
   lines = [v.replace("N", "3") for v in a_file]

# now write the "encrypted" file back using the same name
with open(c, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as a_file:
   a_file.write('Neco jineho napsaneho')
   a_file.writelines(lines)` function for each character, then it works well enough :)

Comment: okay, see my edit. Define an aux function. it will save the read/write.